# Calculating RMSE of test set using SVD recommendation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, svd

I'm trying to calculate the RMSE using truncated SVD on a train-test split MovieLens dataset. After model_selection.train_test_split on the dataset of size 610x9724 (610 users x 9724 movie) ratings from 1-5, the dimensions of the train_data becomes 610x9379 and the dimension of the validation data becomes 603x3653. After doing SVD on the training data, I can calculate the RMSE between the training matrix and the predicted SVD matrix A = U*s*v, but how would I calculate the RMSE of the predicted ratings and the test data which is a different dimensions and a different set of movies than the training data?

Code is below. I can do RMSE between the predicted ratings and the training set but I want to do RMSE between the predicted ratings and the test set.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')

df_train, df_valid = model_selection.train_test_split(
    df, test_size=0.1, random_state=42
)

from sklearn.utils.extmath import randomized_svd

train_data = df_train.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating').fillna(0)
test_data = df_valid.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating')

U, Sigma, VT = randomized_svd(np.array(train_data), 
                              n_components=15,
                              n_iter=5,
                              random_state=None)

predicted = U @ np.diag(Sigma) @ VT
print("full matrix", num_users, num_movies) #full matrix 610 9724
print("train data", train_data.shape) #train data (610, 9379)
print("predicted",predicted.shape) #predicted (610, 9379)
print("validation",test_data.shape) #validation (603, 3653)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_data, predicted))
```